# How to enter this SQL code into .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have a bulk insert that works fine in SQL.

I can't figure out how to get the SQL code to work in C#.

```
CMD.CommandText = "???"
```

I've tried so many ideas and keep getting an error.  The bulk insert is below:

```
Use Lab2
GO
BULK
 INSERT [dbo].[tmpPerson]
  FROM 'C:\Temp\Input2.txt'
   WITH (
      ROWTERMINATOR  ='\n');
```

Comment: Have you tried `BULK INSERT Lab2.[dbo].[tmpPerson] FROM 'C:\Temp\Input2.txt' WITH ( ROWTERMINATOR ='\n');`

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: I can't show the exact error since I'm on my home machine, and the database is on campus.  It has to do with the ending quotation.

My code looked like 

CMD.CommandText = "Use Lab2\n" + "BULK\n" + "INSERT [dbo].[tmpPerson] FROM"+(" 'Input2.txt  WITH (ROWTERMINATOR  = '\n');");



I think the error has to do with the '\n', so how am I supposed to send that in?  I tried surround it in double single quotes, making a string called N= '\n' and I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

How about having a look at [SqlBulkCopy Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

> Lets you efficiently bulk load a SQL Server table with data from
>   another source.
>
> Microsoft SQL Server includes a popular command-prompt utility named
>   bcp for moving data from one table to another, whether on a single
>   server or between servers. The SqlBulkCopy class lets you write
>   managed code solutions that provide similar functionality. There are
>   other ways to load data into a SQL Server table (INSERT statements,
>   for example), but SqlBulkCopy offers a significant performance
>   advantage over them.

Comment: That will work if the source file is local to the Client, but not if its local to the Server (as in the SQL code) and the Server happens to be different from the Client.

Comment: yuo can use a data table to do this, and if you wish to read the file specifically from the server, get it there.

Comment: I'm going to look into this, it may even been taught later in the semester.  My code looks like

CMD.CommandText = "Use Lab2\n" + "BULK\n" + "INSERT [dbo].[tmpPerson] FROM"+(" 'Input2.txt  WITH (ROWTERMINATOR  = '\n');");

I'm 95% sure the error is coming from the '\n'.  I can't really bring up the error code right now because I'm on my home machine, and the database is on campus. It has to do with the ending quotation.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Server object in the Microsoft.SqlServer.management namespace to do this same kind of thing.  It allows you to have the GO word in commands, where using the SqlCommand it expects that each instance of SqlCommand represents a single command.

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```